# Is it possible to import Firefox cookies into Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, import, firefox, cookies, json

I have exported my cookies in Firefox to a TXT file and also to a JSON file.

Is it possible to import either file into Chrome? I have tried a number of extensions from the Chrome Web Store but none seem to import. For example, they ask me to paste the JSON text and I do so but the cookies are not imported.

I am wondering if what I am trying to do is not possible for some reason. Or have I just not found a decent extension yet?